# In R, how to convert numeric 7.00 to time 7:00:00?

Tags: r

In r how to convert a numeric data 7.00 and 19.48 to 7:00:00 and 19:48:00?

ex:

```
a<- 1.05
numeric_time <- as.numeric(a);
a<-paste(floor(numeric_time),round((numeric_time-floor(numeric_time))*100), sep=":")
```

when i execute

> a
>   "1:5" but i need 1:05

Comment: `sub("\\.", ":", a)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strptime` with `format`

```
v2 <- format(strptime(format(v1, nsmall=2), format='%H.%M'), '%H:%M:%S')
v2
#[1] "07:00:00" "19:48:00"
```

If we don't need the leading zero, use `sub` to match the '0' at the beginning (`^`) of the string and replace it with `''`.

```
sub('^0', '', v2)
#[1] "7:00:00"  "19:48:00"
```

Or another option is `sprintf` with `gsub`.  We change the format with `sprintf` and replace the `.` with `:` (similar as @CathG's comment)

```
gsub('[.]', ':', sprintf('%0.2f.00', v1))
#[1] "7:00:00"  "19:48:00"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(7, 19.48)
```